# Redirect URL permanentally to page not found

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting

I have the following issue related to URL rewriting. I am sure there must be some good solution to this.

I converted this URL

```
domainname.com/index.php?page=product&pid=5&proTitle=Samsung Galaxy
```

After rewrite it looks like this

```
domainname.com/products/5/Samsung-Galaxy.html
```

The `.htaccess` code looks like this.

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?page=product&pid=$1&proTitle=$2 [nc]
```

Rewrite Works fine. However, if I try to access old URL i.e `domainname.com/index.php?page=product&pid=5&proTitle=Samsung Galaxy` the page is still accessible and on top of that being crawled by Google and other search engines. I want If someone tries to access this URL, it should direct them to Page Not Found and this should also not be sniffed by any crawlers.

I am sure there must be a smart way of doing this. Awaiting for some valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

in htaccess insert this code :

the code can make the URL "domainname.com/index.php?page=product&pid=5&proTitle=Samsung Galaxy" look 403 Forbidden

insert this for direct if browser find the url is 404 or 403 :

> ErrorDocument 404 /errormessages/404.php
>
> ErrorDocument 403 /errormessages/403.php

you can change the path /errormessage/404.php or 403.php like what you want

and insert this "don't use space" :

---

< IfModule mod_rewrite.c >

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*(\?page=product&pid=$1&proTitle=$2).* [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

< /IfModule >

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try but no success. I am now trying a simplified URL. Here is what it actually looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try but no success. I am now trying a simplified URL. Here is what it actually looks like.

domainname.com/index.php?pg=contactus

the ReWrite URL is as follows.

domainname.com/contact.html

Rewrite Rule is as follows.
'RewriteRule ^contact.html$  index.php?pg=contactus [nc]'

I used code provided by you as follows.
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.(\?pg=contactus). [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]`

It loads both the URL's as stated above. I want this URL to be permanentally moved

domainname.com/index.php?pg=contactus

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should really make the page inaccessible since people might have bookmarked it, and you're just making it harder to get back to where they were.  If your main problem is Google still referencing it, then use rel="canonical" and specify the URL you'd rather have Google use.  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en

Comment: Its a new site just uploaded without URL Rewriting.. so there isn't any chance of a bookmark. Also google bot was very fast to sniff the pages so I don't want any more pages crawled.

Comment: You can use robots.txt to prevent further crawling, and canonical refs to set the preferred URL.  If Google knows about it someone else does too and might follow the link, and you don't know the next time Google will crawl your site.